# Problems with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm having problems with auto layout.
**What I need to do:**
Adjust a view (V1) using auto layout and than set a different view(V2) (custom view with charts) inside of it.
**The Problem:**
When I set the width and height of V1 in storyboard its frame is: 0,0, 600, 300 (size classes is on), at runtime the width of superview is 320, for exemple, but when I try to see the frame of V1 during runtime it still with width 600. 
**My Question:**
Exist a way to find out which is the "real" frame of V1? The width value its assume at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the reason for the problem with finding out the frame is that you are asking for the frame at the wrong time, i.e. too soon. You have to wait until *after* layout has occurred.

But the *real* answer is that you are thinking about this completely wrong. Create V2 and make it a subview of V1, and position and size it *using constraints*. Use auto layout here too! That way, it will be right, relative to V1, no matter *what* happens to V1. You *never* have to know what the frame of V1 is! *That is the whole point of autolayout*!! Don't subvert autolayout or try to work around it; *use* it!

Comment: My book teaches you how to make a view in code, add it to the interface, and apply constraints to it: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autolayout

Comment: Matt thanks for your answer! It makes me think and I found a solution to my problem! I applied auto layout directly on V2 as you said and change some configurations on my charts to load after the view are set.